# Memory leaks with change event that loads each time a new JQuery plugin DataTables

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, datatables

I have problems with memory leaks.

I display a table (with [DataTables plugin](https://datatables.net/)) in my Html page following a select tag (**Select2**) that has an event `change()`.

I noticed some memory leaks with the task manager (IE or FireFox).

My code works well, the only problem is memory leaks.

Here is my Html code, I have 2 tables, the second (**table_statistic_10_ligne**) is displayed when I click on one row of my first table (**table_statistic_10**), it displays the details of this row :

```
<body>
 <select id="Select2" name="D1" style="margin-right :50px">
 </select>
 <script>
    $("#Select2").change(function () { selectStat10(Select2.options[Select2.selectedIndex].value) });
 </script>

 <table id="table_statistic_10" class="display">
    <caption class="caption">Detail van verkopen</caption>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 </table>
  <br />
  <br />

 <table id="table_statistic_10_ligne" class="display">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    fillSlectTagStat10();
 </script>
</body>
```

Here is my javascript code, in the success, I retrieve the values (retrieved from a web service in C#) and I fill them in the datatables :

```
function getStatistic10(dstart, dend, nam) {

var response;
var allstat10 = [];

if (typeof myTabLigne10 != 'undefined') {
    myTabLigne10.fnClearTable();
}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_10_Entete',
        data: { "start": JSON.stringify(dstart), "end": JSON.stringify(dend), "name": JSON.stringify(nam) },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            response = msg.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
                var j = 0;
                allstat10[i] = [response.Items[i].Nom, response.Items[i].Date, response.Items[i].Piece, response.Items[i].Tiers, number_format(response.Items[i].AmoutHT, 2, ',', ' '), number_format(response.Items[i].AmountTTC, 2, ',', ' '), response.Items[i].Quantite];
            }
            if (typeof myTabEntete10 != 'undefined') {
                myTabEntete10.fnClearTable();
            }
            fillDataTableEntete10(allstat10, dstart, dend);

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error loading statistic 10");
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + "\n" + "Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Filling dataTables code :

```
function fillDataTableEntete10(data, dstart, dend) {

if ($("#table_statistic_10").css("visibility") == "hidden")
    $("#table_statistic_10").css("visibility", "visible");

myTabEntete10 = $('#table_statistic_10').dataTable({

    'aaData': data,
    'aoColumns': [
        { "sTitle": "Nom" },
        { "sTitle": "Date" },
        { "sTitle": "Piece" },
        { "sTitle": "Tiers" },
        { "sTitle": "AmoutHT" },
        { "sTitle": "AmountTTC" },
        { "sTitle": "Quantite" }
    ],

    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sDom": '<"top"f<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ilp<"clear">>'


});
```

I have approximately 10 values (customer) in the select tag (**Select2**). But one customer has about 20.000 rows that I fill in the datatables. And when I selected several times this customer, I see that the memory increases.

I used `fnClearTable()` but it doesn't work.

Have you an idea because I'm a little lost?

**EDIT :** I solved the problem, I updtate the DataTables with fnClearTable() and fnAddData(). But now, the problem is with my **click** event, I have memory leaks because of this code :

```
                myTabEntete10.$('tr').bind('click',function () {
                var data = myTabEntete10.fnGetData(this);
                $('tr').removeClass('row_selected');
                $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                loadData10(dstart, dend, data[2], data[3]);
                delete data;
            });
```

Why?

Comment: I am always fairly skeptical of claims of memory leaks from a garbage-collected language. How do you know this "leak" isn't simply that the GC has not yet run?

Comment: I don't konw and it's the problem. I'm not an expert in javascript, I learn step by step. How do you know that gc runned?

Comment: In IE, you can call `CollectGarbage`. In Firefox, see https://adblockplus.org/blog/different-ways-to-force-garbage-collection . Note this should only be done for your testing, not for your production code. Normally the GC runs automatically when required.

Comment: I tested with CollectGarbage, I placed at the beginning of my function getStatistic10(), it doesn't work, is this the right place? When the GC is called? I don't understand why this is not handled automatically?

Comment: It is handled automatically. The problem is in your testing. Just testing a few times and seeing the memory usage go up is not enough. You usually need to test enough to trigger the GC to run due to the amount of memory you have allocated. Or you can try to force it via one of the mechanisms above. Either way though, you can't just run your test a few times and claim a memory leak. You have to give the GC a chance to reclaim memory that is no longer reachable.

Comment: With IE, I tested a few times and I get a memory saturation. You want to know this? Is this normal?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You need to do more investigation. I have not used this, but it looks like IE11 has some tools to give you more information about memory allocations. I would recommend reading this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/09/04/reducing-the-pressure-on-the-garbage-collector-by-using-the-f12-developer-bar-of-internet-explorer-11.aspx

Comment: @DarkFalcon I edited my post if you have an idea?

Comment: What about delegating the event listening to the parent? My initial guess is that a reference to the removed nodes is maintained due to the listener and that prevents it from being garbage-collected.

Comment: I solved the problem, I use `on()` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I replace the DataTables in the existing.

```
if (typeof myTabEntete10 != 'undefined') {
   $('body').off("click", '#table_statistic_10 tbody tr');
   myTabEntete10.fnClearTable();
   myTabEntete10.fnAddData(allstat10);

} else {
   fillDataTableEntete10(allstat10, dstart, dend);
}
```

And I use the `bDeferRender`option of DataTables, see [here](http://datatables.net/faqs#speed).